# How to couple these variables $X$ and $Y$?

Tags: probability, proof-verification

[image]

Is this a valid solution?

$a) 1/6$ since we have a $1/6$ chance of $Y$ being the same as $X$.

$b)$ Define $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=1/6$ if $x=y$ and $0$ otherwise.

$c)$ Define $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$ and $1/30$ otherwise.

$d)$ Define $f_{X,Y}(x,y)=1/18$ if $x>y$, $1/36$ if $x=y$ and $0$ otherwise.

I am struggling to do these types of questions and these are the answers I can think to come up with. All the probabilities sum to $1$ and I think these are valid.

Comment: The first three are good. For the last one, you did not make sure $X$ and $Y$ are uniform.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean? I did not consider uniformity when answering these problems?

Comment: For d) let $X=Y+1$ if $Y<6$ and $X=1$ otherwise.

Comment: Could you explain how you generated this and why it works please? I need more explanation so I can understand how to solve these types of problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more explicit formulation that is based on the work that you have.

Specifying the distribution of $(X,Y)$ is basically filling the $6 \times 6$ table of the joint probabilities $f(x,y)$, as you have done.

\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
&1&2&\cdots&6\\ \hline
1\\
2\\
\vdots\\
6
\end{array}

- For it to be a probability distribution, each number must be in $[0,1]$, and the sum of the $36$ numbers must be $1$.
- Throughout, you need the marginal distributions of $X$ and $Y$ to be uniform (first line of the question statement). That means the row sums and column sums of your table each must be $1/6$.
- Lastly, you just need to satisfy the condition a), b), c), or d).

You've recognized that drhab's b) matches your b). This is just placing "$1/6$" along the main diagonal. It satisfies the above three conditions.

drhab's c) puts "$1/6$"s along the opposite diagonal. Your c) divides the probabilities evenly among the entries where $x \ne y$. Both satisfy the above three conditions.

drhab's d) puts $1/6$ in the following manner
\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
X, Y &1&2&3&4&5&6\\ \hline
1 & & 1/6\\
2 &&& 1/6\\
3 &&&& 1/6\\
4 &&&&& 1/6\\
5 &&&&&&1/6\\
6 &1/6
\end{array}
You can see that it satisfies the above three conditions. On the other hand, your solution did not satisfy the second condition. For example, the first row sum is $P(X=1)=1/36 \ne 1/6$.

Comment: @RyanS I hope that this nice answer (+1) will bring you up again ("...it's bringing me down..."). You sounded a bit depressed yesterday. Cheer up and go on struggling with motto: **luctor et emergo**.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y$ have uniform distribution on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and define:

b) $X:=Y$

c) $X:=7-Y$

d) $X:=Y+1$ if $Y<6$ and $X:=1$ if $Y=6$

In all cases it can be shown that $X$ has also uniform distribution on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ and secondly that the mentioned conditions are satisfied.

Comment: Could you explain how you managed to generate these answers and explain the process of how to do them?

Comment: They just flip up in my mind (as a consequence of mathematical maturity, I think) and it is quite hard to explain how. Are you able to verify my answer, i.e. that in all cases $X$ has the same distribution as $Y$ and also that the conditions are satisfied?

Comment: No I am not unfortunately I really am struggling so much with this type of problem I just don't understand it at all and it's bringing me down. I think I can maybe for the first one, since $X=Y$ then we have $X$ can take on the values $1,...6$ and so $Y$ has the same each with probability $1/6$ so that sums to $1$ and they are uniform since each value for $X$ has the same probability namely $1/6$

Comment: In b) $X$ and $Y$ exactly the same random variables. Then automatically they have the same distribution and automatically $\Pr(X=Y)=1$. Do you see that?

Comment: See my edit above.

Comment: Does that mean that you do not see that? If so then here it stops, This is not the right place for a full college in the basics of probability. I can only advice you to have a good look at your math texts. Btw, I am leaving now. Tomorrow I might have a second look.